# Using IEnumerator for Onclick function in a Button, but scenemanager doesnt work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently creating a crossfade animation for my Unity Game. In my pause menu, am fading to a black screen by clicking the menu button. When I do this, the menu button doesn't go to the menu scene. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Pause : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject PauseMenuUI;

bool isPaused = false;

public GameObject PauseMenu;
public GameObject OptionsMenu;

public Animator Transition;
public int TransitionTime = 1;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        // Open or close the pause menu
        if (!isPaused)
        {
            OpenPauseMenu();
        }
        else if (isPaused)
        {
            Resume();
        }
    }
}

// Main Menu
void OpenPauseMenu()
{
    PauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);

    Time.timeScale = 0f;

    isPaused = true;
}

public void Resume()
{
    Back();

    PauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);

    Time.timeScale = 1f;

    isPaused = false;
}

public void Options()
{
    PauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    OptionsMenu.SetActive(true);
}

public void Menu()
{
    Resume();
    Crossfade();
}

// Options Menu
public void Back()
{
    OptionsMenu.SetActive(false);
    PauseMenu.SetActive(true);
}

// Crossfade
IEnumerator Crossfade()
{
    Transition.SetTrigger("Start");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TransitionTime);

    SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:unityscript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C# (and I have thus removed it for you). Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the question and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: @Remy, ok, sory...

Answer (score 1):

Methods returning `IEnumerators` are not magic; they can be used to describe a coroutine, but you need to start that coroutine if you want to do something. If you call such a method like a regular method, it'll execute up until the first `yield return` statement, and then nothing else will happen.

Pass the enumerator to `StartCoroutine` to execute the rest of the method:

```
StartCoroutine(Crossfade());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As I said, I am a beginner, so that really helps!